# bootstrap 3.3.4 not apply on IE8 browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

On my website bootstrap 3.3.4 not support ,so please help me to solve out this issue.

Please look out my website on IE8:
http://sandbox.bluepark.fr/assets/airport-pages/basel

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is not being fully supported for bootstrap 3.3.4.
You need to be aware of some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements.

Please refer this link
[Bootstrap Browser Support](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)

IE 8 requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support.
[Respond.JS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: i already use this all type of code in my site,but it not working .